# Tensorflow 2.0 utilize all CPU cores 100%

Tags: tensorflow, cpu, preprocessor

My Tensorflow model makes heavy use of data preprocessing that should be done on the CPU to leave the GPU open for training.

```
top - 09:57:54 up 16:23,  1 user,  load average: 3,67, 1,57, 0,67
Tasks: 400 total,   1 running, 399 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 19,1 us,  2,8 sy,  0,0 ni, 78,1 id,  0,0 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
MiB Mem :  32049,7 total,    314,6 free,   5162,9 used,  26572,2 buff/cache
MiB Swap:   6779,0 total,   6556,0 free,    223,0 used.  25716,1 avail Mem 

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                
  17604 joro      20   0   22,1g   2,3g 704896 S 331,2   7,2   4:39.33 python
```

This is what top shows me. I would like to make this python process use at least 90% of available CPU across all cores. How can this be achieved?

GPU utilization is better, around 90%. Even though I don't know why it is not at 100%

```
Mon Aug 10 10:00:13 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.100      Driver Version: 440.100      CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 35%   41C    P2    90W / 260W |  10515MiB / 11016MiB |     11%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1128      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           102MiB |
|    0      1648      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           380MiB |
|    0      1848      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         279MiB |
|    0     10633      G   ...uest-channel-token=1206236727             266MiB |
|    0     13794      G   /usr/lib/firefox/firefox                       6MiB |
|    0     17604      C   python                                      9457MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

All i found was a solution for tensorflow 1.0:

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
  intra_op_parallelism_threads=NUM_THREADS))
```

I have an Intel 9900k and a RTX 2080 Ti and use Ubuntu 20.04

E: When I add the following code on top, it uses 1 core 100%

```
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(1)
tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(1)
```

But increasing this number to 16 again only utilizes all cores ~30%

Comment: The Os determines this not the code. Also number of threads does not equal CPU utilisation, again the OS will schedule the threads. Most OS actively try and prevent 100% CPU utilisation as it will mean the OS won't work.

Comment: Can I force the OS to give more computational power to a process? It seems to me that my OS limits python to exactly 3 cores at 100%

Comment: I had similar issues witth tensorflow but could not solve it. I can only conclude that there is excessive blocking going on and so their code doesn't scale at all. We dropped TF because of it.

Comment: That's a blow.. but I can see the reason, the CPU limitation for me right now is a huge bottleneck since I would have power to train around 3 times faster

Comment: i have a similar problem, we tried to do a work-around using docker with a set of limitation in term of CPU and GPU. it works but not as we need it. so start using darknet instead with some images utilities.

Answer (score 7):

Just setting the `set_intra_op_parallelism_threads`  and `set_inter_op_parallelism_threads`  wasn't working for me. Incase someone else is in the same place, after a lot of struggle with the same issue, below piece of code worked for me in limiting the CPU usage of tensorflow below 500%:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
num_threads = 5
os.environ["OMP_NUM_THREADS"] = "5"
os.environ["TF_NUM_INTRAOP_THREADS"] = "5"
os.environ["TF_NUM_INTEROP_THREADS"] = "5"

tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(
    num_threads
)
tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(
    num_threads
)
tf.config.set_soft_device_placement(True)
```

Comment: I'm running it on Jupiter notebook however it doesn't seem to work. From total processes:390, 3 running. I've set both configs to "300".

Answer (score 1):

There can be many issues for this, I solved it for me the following way:

Set
`tf.config.threading.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(<Your_Physical_Core_Count>) tf.config.threading.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(<Your_Physical_Core_Count>)`

both to your *physical* core count. You do not want Hyperthreading for highly vectorized operations as you cannot benefit from parallized operations when there aren't any gaps.

> "With a high level of vectorization, the number of execution gaps is
> very small and there is possibly insufficient opportunity to make up
> any penalty due to increased contention in HT."

From: Saini et al, published by NASAA dvanced Supercomputing Division, 2011: The Impact of Hyper-Threading on Processor
Resource Utilization in Production Applications

EDIT: I am not sure anymore, if one of the two has to be 1. But one 100% needs to be set to Physical.